# the best description for a specific style of building (Central European type)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

[image]

I'm looking for the best description of a particular type of apartments. I also attach a picture to illustrate what I'm trying to say.
There is a building in which there are several apartments on each story. Each apartment is formed of one or more rooms, where someone would walk from one room to another without using a connecting hallway. The hallway is part of the common space of the building, the story itself, on which everyone walks between apartments. 
I need a better description for this. also, is there a particular style--as in architectural style--that best describes this specific configuration?
thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

From your description

> *There is a building in which there are several apartments on each story.*

This is usually called **an apartment building**

> *Each apartment is formed of one or more rooms, where someone would walk from one room to another without using a connecting hallway.*

This is a standard configuration for **a self-contained apartment** where the bathroom and kitchen are integral parts of the whole apartment.

> *The hallway is part of the common space of the building, the story itself, on which everyone walks between apartments.*

Usually hallways are considered to be ***internal***, but you are showing an external balconey, which is a style used in areas of warmer climate.

**An apartment building** or **apartment block** may be the phrase you are looking for.

In the UK, many Council flats (subsidized housing) have this format

[image]

Comment: In the uk this would be a "block of flats"

Answer (score 0):

the external corridors you describe were called "streets in the sky" when they were conceived, there were supposed to replace the streets people living in the replaced back to back terraces had all of their community on.

This one is a listed building
[Park Hill sheffield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Park_Hill,_Sheffield)